# How can I get touch co-ordinates in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

What I want is that wherever user touches on iPhone screen, where I will display a pic at that place.
Can anyone help me how to get co-ordinates of the area everytime when user touches the screen?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say you are using cocos2d, but you tagged your question as such.  I will assume this is the case.

You need to put code in your `ccTouchesEnded` function.  This is basically what it looks like:

```
-(BOOL)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
     CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

     CCSprite *myImage = [CCSprite spriteWihFile: @"myImage.png"];
     [myImage setPosition: location];
     [self addChild: myImage];

     return YES;
 }
```

It sounds like you might need more help than that.  If so, you should go to the cocos2d iphone page and look through the setup and tutorials.

Comment: This code works well, but I've changed app's orientation to portrait and now Y axis seems to be kinda flipped. I mean when I touch the screen at the left top corner, image appears at the left bottom corner. Any ideas why it happens?